# Python3.6, OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected

Tags: python, networking

I was trying to write a protocol like UDP in python, which include some details like three_handshake, but I can't run the server.py cause it told me like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/suiyoucheng/PycharmProjects/9331 ASS/receiver.py", line 
38, in <module>
BYTE_fh, senderAddress = receiverSocket.recvfrom(1024)
OSError: [Errno 57] Socket is not connected
```

and my server.py code shown as below:

```
try:
    receiverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
except:
    print("Failed to create receiver socket.")
    sys.exit()


receivePort = 2000
try:
    receiverSocket.bind(('', receivePort))
except:
    print("Bind failed.")
    sys.exit()

#                           First Hand Shake                              #

receiver_ISN = 0
receiver_ITIME = time.time()


BYTE_fh, senderAddress = receiverSocket.recvfrom(1024) #**where I got wrong**#
first_hand = pickle.loads(BYTE_fh)
```

Could you guys tell me how to fix that? Thank you so much.

Comment: You can't receive anything from the server socket if a client hasn't connected to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start listening for connections before you can read the data from the socket.
Please add receiverSocket.listen() and receiverSocket.accept() after the bind().
Rather than using raw socket, you can use the [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socketserver.html) as well.

The overall steps that need to be taken for creating a server (without exception handling):

```
srvsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = (socket.gethostname(), 25000)
srvsock.bind(server_address)
srvsock.listen(5)
connection, client_address = srvsock.accept()
data = connection.recv(1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a client socket as well to test the server. Below is a more complete ClientSocket class that can be used. You can use the function cnsdrcv() for a one time send-receive interaction. The same class can also be used on the server-side for interacting with the client connections -

```
connection, client_address = serverSocket.accept()
clntCon = ClientSocket()
clntCon.useSocket(connection).connect()
dataBytes = clntCon.rcvAllSent()
# Process all the "dataBytes" and then respond back
clntCon.send(responseBytes)
clntCon.close()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def cnsdrcv(host, port, data, timeout=1):
  # data - bytes()
  # returns data chunks as list of bytes()

  # Create a TCP/IP socket
  sock = ClientSocket()
  sock.useHost(host, port, timeout)

  try:
    sock.connect()

    # Send data
    sock.send(data)

    return sock.rcvUntilTimeout()
  finally:
    sock.close()
```

The complete class below -

```
class ClientSocket:

  def __init__(self, name=None):
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : __init__()".format(name))
    self.Name = name
    self.sock = None
    self.server_address = None

  @property
  def Name(self):
    if self.__Name is None and self.server_address is not None:
      self.Name = str(self.server_address[1])

    return self.__Name

  @Name.setter
  def Name(self, name):
    self.__Name = name

  @Name.deleter
  def Name(self):
    del self.__Name


  def useSocket(self, sock, timeout=1):
    # Socket is assumed to be already connected
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : useSocket()".format(self.Name))

    if sock is None:
      raise ValueError("ClientSocket.useSocket() : sock arg cannot be None")

    if self.sock is None:
      self.server_address = sock.getpeername()
      self.sock = sock
      self.timeout = timeout
      self.sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
      return self
    else:
      raise AttributeError("ClientSocket.useSocket() : is already in use")


  def useHost(self, host, port, timeout=1):
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : useHost()".format(self.Name))

    if host == None or len(host) == 0:
      host = socket.gethostname()
    self.server_address = (host, port)
    self.timeout = timeout


  def connect(self):
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : connect()".format(self.Name))

    if self.sock is None:
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
      self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      logging.info('connecting to {} port {}'.format(*self.server_address))

      # Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
      self.sock.connect(self.server_address)
      self.sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
    else:
      self.isValid()


  def isValid(self):
    if not self.sock:
      return False

    try:
      if self.sock.fileno() == -1:
    except:
      return False

    try:
      self.sock.getsockname()
    except socket.error as e:
      if e.args[0] == errno.EBADF:
        # Socket is CLOSED
        pass
      return False

    try:
      self.sock.getpeername()
    except socket.error as e:
      if e.args[0] in [errno.EBADF, errno.ENOTCONN]:
        # Socket is CLOSED
        pass
      return False

    return True


  def send(self, data):
    # data must be a bytes or Data object
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : send()".format(self.Name))

    logging.debug('sending {!r}'.format(data))

    if not self.isValid() :
      logging.error("Client Socket in BAD state, cannot send")

    if isinstance(data, str):
      data = data.encode()

    try:
      # Send data
      self.sock.sendall(data)
    except:
      raise

  def rcvOnce(self, rcvSz, timeout=5):
    # receive at least one byte, waiting for timeout secs
    # returns bytes containing max rcvSz bytes
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : rcvOnce()".format(self.Name))

    if not self.isValid() :
      logging.error("Client Socket in BAD state, cannot receive")
      return None

    strtTime = time.time()
    while True:
      try:
        chunk = self.sock.recv(rcvSz)
        break
      except socket.timeout:
        logging.debug("Socket recv timedout, re-trying")
        if time.time() - strtTime >= timeout:
          raise
        continue
      except:
        logging.exception("Receive exception")
        raise

    if chunk is None or len(chunk) == 0:
      logging.debug("Received len [0]")
    else:
      logging.debug("Received len [{}]".format(len(chunk)))

    return chunk

  def rcvAllSent(self, timeout=5):
    # Returns a Data object
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : rcvAllSent()".format(self.Name))

    if not self.isValid() :
      logging.error("Client Socket in BAD state, cannot receive")
      return None

    chunks = []
    strtTime = time.time()
    while True:
      try:
        chunk = self.sock.recv(1024)
      except socket.timeout as e:
        logging.debug("Read Timeout occurred [{}]".format(e))
        if time.time() - strtTime >= timeout:
          raise
        continue
      except socket.error as e:
        logging.error("Some Socket error occurred [{}]".format(e))
        break
      else:
        if len(chunk) == 0:
          logging.info("Received empty chunk, could be due to socket close()")
          break
        else:
          chunks.append(chunk)
          if len(chunk) < 1024:
            break
          else:
            continue

    return b''.join(chunks)

  def rcvUntilTimeout(self, rcvSz=2048):
    # returns a list of received bytes() objects
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : rcvUntilTimeout()".format(self.Name))

    if not self.isValid() :
      logging.error("Client Socket in BAD state, cannot receive")
      return None

    chunks  = []
    tchunkb = []

    chunk = self.rcvOnce(rcvSz)
    if chunk is None or len(chunk) == 0:
      # Socket closed by the remote
      return None
    else:
      chunks.append(chunk)

    while True:
      try:
        chunkb = self.sock.recv(rcvSz)
      except socket.timeout as e:
        logging.debug("Socket recv timedout")
        break
      except socket.error:
        logging.exception("Socket recv error")
        raise
      except:
        logging.exception("Unknown Exception while recv")
        raise
      else:
        if len(chunkb) == 0:
          logging.info("Received empty chunk indicating remote end closed the socket")
          break
        else:
          logging.debug("Received len [{}]".format(len(chunkb)))
          tchunkb.append(chunkb)
          if len(chunkb) < rcvSz:
            chunks.append(b''.join(tchunkb))
            tchunkb = []
          else:
            continue

    return chunks

  def close(self):
    logging.debug("ClientSocket [{}] : close()".format(self.Name))

    if self.isValid():
      self.sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
      self.sock.close()
```