# Socket Server with multiply Clients

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I just started programming Python.
My goal is to built a digital Picture Frame with three Screens. Therefore I use 3 Raspis, one for each Monitor.
For the communication of these Raspis I need to program a server and a Client.

For a first test I want to built a server which is able to send and receive messages to/from multiple clients.
So I started with a few socket tutorials an created the following program.

Server Class (TcpServer.py)

```
class TcpServer:
    clients = []

    serverIsRunning = 0
    port = 0
    
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        self.serverIsRunning = 0
        self.serverRunning = 0
    
    
    
    def startServer (self):
        print("start Server...")
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
        self.server.bind(("", self.port))                                     
        self.server.listen(1)                                            
        self.serverRunning = 1
        while self.serverRunning: 
            read, write, oob = select.select([self.server] + self.clients, [], []) 
            for sock in read: 
                if sock is self.server: 
                    client, addr = self.server.accept() 
                    self.clients.append(client) 
                    print ("+++ Client ", addr[0], " verbunden")
                else: 
                    nachricht = sock.recv(1024) 
                    ip = sock.getpeername()[0] 
                    if nachricht: 
                        print (ip, nachricht) 
                    else: 
                        print ("+++ Verbindung zu ", ip , " beendet")
                        sock.close() 
                        self.clients.remove(sock) 
        for c in self.clients: 
            c.close()
            self.clients.remove(c) 
        self.server.close()
            
    def send(self, message):
        message = message.encode()
        self.server.send(message)
```

Client class (TcpClient.py)

```
import socket

class TcpClient:

    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.serverAdress = (ip, port)
        self.connected = 0
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect(self.serverAdress)
        print ("connectet to ", self.serverAdress)

    def send(self, message):
        message = message.encode()
        self.connection.send(message)
```

Server:

```
import threading
import TcpServer

tcpServer = TcpServer.TcpServer(50000)

threadTcpServer = threading.Thread(target = tcpServer.startServer)
threadTcpServer.start()

while True:
    tcpServer.send(input("Nachricht eingeben: "))
```

Client:

```
import threading
import TcpClient

tcpClient = TcpClient.TcpClient("192.168.178.49", 50000)

while True:
    tcpClient.send(input("Nachricht eingeben: "))
```

I can send messages from the Client to the server, but when I want to send a Message from the server to the client it generates the following error:

> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I assume it is because the server thread blocks the socket while waiting of a incoming message. But I have no idea how to handle this.
How can I program a server who can send and receive messages? Can you recommend a tutorial? I didn't found a tutorial who describes a solution for my problem.

**Edit:**

Now I tried to solve the problem with the socketserver library, but I still can't solve may problem.
here is my new code for the server:

```
import socketserver
import threading
import time

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(self.data)
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    threadTcpServer = threading.Thread(target = server.serve_forever)
    threadTcpServer.start()

    print("server started")
    
    time.sleep(10)
    
    print("sending Data")
    server.request.sendall("Server is sending...")
```

it generates the error:

> AttributeError: 'TCPServer' object has no attribute 'request'

My goal is to write a server with a thread who receives Data and still be able to send data from a other thread.
Is this even possible with only one socket?

Comment: Is your requirement more like broadcasting of data from different machines/raspis and simultaneously receive the broadcasts on all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the provided [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) rather than writing all the handling of sockets and select etc.

There are multiple problems with your code -

1 - The server is trying to write to the listening socket!! The client communication socket is the one that you get from the accept() call and that is the one you have to use for reading and writing.

2 - The client is sending the data and completing immediately, but it should really wait for getting a response. Otherwise, the python / OS will close the client socket as soon as the program completes and it will mostly be before the server gets a chance to respond.

Comment: You can go over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789022/python3-6-oserror-errno-57-socket-is-not-connected/52789294). It has a very simple server with a bit evolved client class that can be used. If this is helpful, then I can share a more enhanced server as well. But I still recommend using the python in-built socketserver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with the Handler code you are able to receive the data sent by the client on the server and are also able to send some data back from the Handler to the client? You must have understood that the server cannot send any data back unless there is a client connected to it?

Now, to send data to the client (or clients) from "another" thread, you will need a way to make the handler objects or the client sockets (available inside the Handler object as `self.request`) available to the "another" thread.

One way is to override the `def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):` method and save `this` object's reference in a global list. Remember to do the below as the last line of the overridden **init** -

```
# BaseRequestHandler __init__ must be the last statement as all request processing happens in this method
socketserver.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
```

Once you have all the client handlers in the global list, you can easily write to all the clients from any thread as per your needs. You must read about synchronization (Locks) and understand that using same object / socket from multiple threads can create some logical / data issues with your application.

Another thing that you have to worry about and code for is cleaning up this global list whenever a client closes the connection.